# rescue_from StandardError overridding other rescue_from blocks

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-6

I am trying to create a module that handles API errors that I `include` in my `application_controller.rb`. Here is my module's `self.included` function.

```
def self.included(clazz)
  clazz.class_eval do

    rescue_from ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound do |e|
      respond(:record_not_found, 404, e.message)
    end
    rescue_from ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid do |e|
      respond(:record_invalid, 422, e.record.errors.full_messages)
    end
    rescue_from ActionController::ParameterMissing do |e|
      respond(:bad_request, 400, e.message)
    end
    rescue_from StandardError do |e|
      respond(:standard_error, 500, e.message)
    end
  end
end
```

The problem I am having is that `StandardError` catches all errors including the other errors I have defined in the other `rescue_from` blocks.

I want to achieve something like this instead:

```
begin

rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound => e

rescue ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid => e

rescue ActionController::ParameterMissing => e

rescue StandardError => e

end
```

Thanks for the help in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would refactor this into a single `rescue_from` and then drill down by checking `e.class`:

```
rescue_from StandardError do |e|
  case e.class
  when ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
    respond(:record_not_found, 404, e.message)
  when ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid
    respond(:record_invalid, 422, e.record.errors.full_messages)
  when ActionController::ParameterMissing
    respond(:record_not_found, 400, e.message)
  else
    respond(:standard_error, 500, e.message)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that [`rescue_from`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Rescuable/ClassMethods.html#method-i-rescue_from) handlers are

> Handlers are inherited. They are searched from right to left, from bottom to top, and up the hierarchy.

This means that the blocks are executed in reverse order so your 4 `rescue_from`s look more like:

```
begin
rescue StandardError => e
rescue ActionController::ParameterMissing => e
rescue ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid => e
rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound => e
end
```

instead. The fact that the last handler added is the first one executed allows things such as a child controller to override a handler in a parent controller. So, to fix, simply reverse the order you define your `rescue_from` blocks and things should work as you intended.